# Experiment with two groups, pre- and post- treatment assessments

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures, t-test

I am conducting an experiment with a control group and a treatment group. Both groups will take a pre and post treatment depression inventory. What statistical procedure do I use to determine if the treatment reduced depressive symptoms significantly? 
T-test or ANOVA, which kind and why?